# Code-formating isn't explained clearly enough

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I wrote a Question on Stackoverflow and when I wanted to submit it, it says:

> "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon"

And there was only one code snippet, but already formatted in the following way:`<code>

function("value1", "value2")

</code>`
which looks like 

`function("value1", "value2")`

So I was wondering, what you want from me..
It would be nice if you would mark up the part you mean with that message and/or tell that `<code></code>` isn't a proper code-formating if you do it like that... 
or just make it a proper code-formating..

then I changed it too

``` ``

function("value1", "value2") ```


(omg.. that was kinda hard to represent o.O)

Which wasn't working either.. wait... nope it worked.. but I ain'T knew it back then, and it seems that I made a typo or something so that I got the message again...

Sadly I first recognized that the Problem with `<code></code>` is, that I'm not allowed to put them in different rows, while writing this "question"...

ooh.. and it would be great if you could explain the difference between the 
`<code></code>` and the ``` `` ``` formating...
cause while writing this I allready noticed some differences...

EDIT:
This isn't just a duplicate of "How do I format my code blocks?", because I didn't wanted to know how to format code-blocks, I had the wish(feature-request) that you could maybe change your errormessage(the one I quoted), in a way that everybody knews what to do..

I mean I even checked on the right side, below "How to format", "what HTML tags are allowed" and when there is written that `<code></code>` is possible, how shall I or somebody else know that it's not allowed to use it in that way?
It's not even an "Important Note"...

Comment: I think you're ascribing to much intelligence to the computer, it just knows somethings wrong. If it knew how to fix it it would just fix it

Comment: There's no difference between `<code></code>` and using `.

Comment: Also <code> tags may work, but you're not supposed to use them at all, it's ` `some code` ` for single lines and indented for long code

Comment: @3ventic ooh there are differences!!! just try to use &gt; in <code></code> and than in ``

Answer (score 0):

It wants indenting.  Select the code you want to format, and click the `{}` button above the editor window.

Comment: That was what I did in the end...